# UIPageViewController partial curl from code

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uipageviewcontroller

Is there any possiblity to curl partially the page from code with UIPageViewController. I want to show the user that he is able to change pages, in order to do that I want to partially curl the page and put it back (slight swipe left and then right, this would be the input from the user to get this effect but I want it from code).

Comment: You found anything useful?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp`. Checkout the example below.

```
- (void)handleSwipe:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)sender {

if(sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp forView:window cache:YES];

    [self.view addSubview:[newView view]];
    [oldView removeFromSuperview];

    [UIView commitAnimations];
   }                  
}
- (void)createGestureRecognizers:(UIView *) target {
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *rightSwipeRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipe:)];

[rightSwipeRecognizer setDirection:(UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight)];
[target addGestureRecognizer:rightSwipeRecognizer];
[rightSwipeRecognizer release];
}
```

Comment: It's not at all what I want. I want to bend the page to reflect that it can be change with swipe gesture. I don't want to change views with some animations.

Comment: I want this too! UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp is no solution for this problem.
Maybe there is some way to fake the GestureRecognizers for the transition?